# Unicode subscripts in ggplot labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make ggplots that need mixtures of greek letters and subscripts and such throughout the labels and legends. I know that two options involve using "expression" or directly using unicode. I believe that unicode will be best for my purposes, since I will eventually be pasting lots of things together and was having trouble getting that to work with expressions.

Does anyone know why the subscript j unicode symbol won't show up in ggplot? The unocideo subscript I works great- is j just not built in? Are there ways to trouble shoot this? I have attached a very simple example where the X axis label looks great but the Y axis label fails.

```
ggplot(data=NULL, aes(x=1:10, y=1:10))+geom_point()+
  xlab("\u039B\u1D62")+ylab("\u039B\u2C7C")
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: I tested your code and it seems to work, the j subscript on the y axis label is correctly being displayed

Comment: It works fine for me. That said, you could do `xlab(~ Lambda[i])+ylab(~ Lambda[j])`

Comment: This works fine for me too.  Sorry to say, OP, but your issue is not reproducible.

Comment: Interesting-- thank you!! I will try to update my RStudio or something. The J subscripts do not display for me.